# What is the name of this small town in Italy somewhere outside of Rome?

Tags: italy, identify-this

Twenty-odd years ago, my wife and son and I were lost in the Italian countryside somewhere between Rome and Venice (not a bad thing except we were low on gas) and we stumbled on a beautiful tiny town whose name was then lost.  Until recently!  I found some postcards my wife (now deceased) had kept a travel diary on, and she's recorded the name of the town.  But I can't read it!

She wrote that we had gotten off the autostrada at Tivoli (which seems possible but I can't say for sure) and drove for quite a while through windy two-lane roads without seeing any towns until this little beauty.

Any help deciphering her handwriting?  It looks like San Gregorino to me, but there's no town by that name.  I will also say that in my memory, there wasn't a castle, just a town wall, but as I say it was twenty-odd years ago and anything is possible.

[image]

Comment: Note that -ino is a diminutive ending in Italian: in principle it is possible that any small church or town devoted to S. Gregorio could be colloquially known as "San Gregorino" among the locals.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[San Gregorio da Sassola](https://goo.gl/maps/Nj2t8J9hEhfSf91n6)?

- 10-15 km from Tivoli via narrow winding roads
- Small town (population about 1500)
- Appropriate name, if the "n" was a mistake
- Site of [Castello Brancaccio](https://goo.gl/maps/HAq7pTsfr7auvhuq7).

Answer (score 33):

Gas station AND Castle... Don't tell me it's your car too getting refueled...
[San Gregorio da Sassola]
[image]

(Image from [Google Street View](https://goo.gl/maps/mQ6jV1TtEeADj2Yx6))

Comment: Unless that's a 20 year old pic, probably not the OP's car. If it _is_ a 20 yo pic and that is the OP's car, that's... _amazing_!

Comment: @FreeMan no need to destroy his joke by overthinking it

Comment: Where did you get this photo?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-: Evidently Google Street View, given the arrows.  I added attribution and a link.  user122523: in future please provide attribution to images or other third-party content included in your posts.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh lol my brain didn't even see those

Comment: Alas!  (1) We took no pictures on that day, (2) my car was red, and (3) Google Street View was still science fiction (grin)